# Controlling android sound settings

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application that helps manage notification sound settings. It should allow people to set a "quiet time" when the phone will go into silent mode automatically, and so on. It is easy enough to change the volume to silent using the `AudioManager` system service.

I was wondering whether there is a way to **allow only phone calls from specific people to ring**, and others to be muted. This would be useful when you don't want to be disturbed in the middle of the night, but still remain available for emergencies. Does the `TelephonyManager`'s state change listener trigger early enough to allow the ring to be squelched before it starts?

What about **only letting certain apps make a sound?**

Are there any API features I could use for these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TelephonyManager` can indeed be used to allow phone calls only from certain people to ring.

For example:

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
class PhoneRingingListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING && !incomingNumber.equals("important number"))
        {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
    }
}

tm.listen(new PhoneRingingListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Will mute the phone when anyone but "important number" phones. This triggers before the phone actually starts ringing.

I haven't found anything to mute certain apps